# pip with sudo, but pip lists the packages outdate

Tags: python, pip

I install some of following packages with sudo pip3, but pip prints the outdate packages again. How to install them successfully?

```
 Package                      Version   Latest      Type
---------------------------- --------- ----------- -----
bleach                       1.5.0     2.0.0       wheel
html5lib                     0.9999999 0.999999999 wheel
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions 0.3.0     0.3.1       wheel
...
murmurhash                   0.26.4    0.28.0      sdist
nbconvert                    5.2.1     5.3.1       wheel
pyasn1-modules               0.1.1     0.1.4       wheel


⇒  sudo pip3 install html5lib

Password:
The directory '/Users/william/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/william/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: html5lib in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from html5lib)**
```

Comment: Are you using `pip` or `pip3` to list the packages?

Comment: pip3, I always use 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update/upgrade a package using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071256/how-to-update-upgrade-a-package-using-pip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to upgrade an already installed package, you need to pass the [`--upgrade`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-u) flag to `pip install`, e.g.:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade html5lib
```