# No module named 'selenium.webdriver.chrome'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
1from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("www.youtube.com")
```

Never had this problem, although I installed selenium like a year ago it worked just fine then:

```
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/CleverBotBot.py", line 2, in <module>
from .chrome.webdriver import WebDriver as Chrome  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.chrome
```

already tried with the firefox gekodriver, makes the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this problem simply uninstal your selenium:
    pip3 uninstall selenium
and install it again
    pip3 install selenium

Comment: Or check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071256/how-to-update-upgrade-a-package-using-pip

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
pip.exe install selenium
```

instead of

```
pip install selenium
```

It worked for me.