# youtube_dl has not uninstall

Tags: uninstallation, youtube-dl

I want to remove youtube_dl from vscode and reinstall it. But it cannot be removed.
(You can also import the youtube_dl module by typing the command below.)

I tried :
`# pip uninstall youtube_dl`
`# brew uninstall youtub-dl`

I can't remember how I installed youtube_dl before. How can I uninstall and reinstall?
Or is there a way to upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Brew

You can try

```sh
$ brew reinstall youtube-dl
```

Or

```sh
$ brew uninstall youtube-dl
$ brew autoremove
$ brew cleanup
$ brew install youtube-dl
```

For upgrading use

```sh
$ brew update
$ brew upgrade youtube-dl
```

### Pip

The install and uninstall commands for pip are

```sh
$ pip uninstall youtube-dl
$ pip install youtube-dl
```

To [upgrade with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47071257/9993933)

```sh
$ pip install youtube-dl --upgrade
```